# What factors affect the calculation of an element's width and height?

Tags: html, css

What I have is an element whose styling is broken: the width and height are quite wrong. The problem is that there is no `width` or `height` specified on this element: if you look at it in Chrome Dev Tools, you see those properties are greyed out, as seen below, because they're just being calculated by the browser based on other information.

[image]

And comparing diffs between commits, I can see no styling rules were changed on this element. Which means something *around* the element was changed: one of its many children, or a parent.

What I would like to know is how can you determine what elements or rules are affecting that calculation, so as to debug it?

I am hoping there is sort of a checklist, something like "Check width property on all child elements. If it is set, then ..., otherwise move on to look at possible JavaScript affecting ... "

**Edit:** The question can be rephrased as ""What factors do browsers check, in what order and with what priority, to determine an element's dimensions?"

Comment: Without seeing the code, many things affect width and height. Content is probably the biggest, so is width of parents or adjacent elements if they're floated, etc.

Comment: This question should not require seeing the code. It's essentially this: "What factors do browsers check, in what order and with what priority, to determine an element's dimensions?" That is code-agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these specifications: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height

There are a few different types of height calculations, as outlined in section 10.6. Take a look at the subsections there to determine how the height of your element is being calculated.

(There's a warning of some of the sections on that page being updated by other specifications, but a quick check on the updates doesn't seem to include any changes for height.)